# Full page sidebar/column?

Tags: semantic-ui

I want to make layout like http://purecss.io/layouts/blog/ using Semantic UI

Can you tell me how to do that ?

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blog Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/semantic.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui padded grid">
            <div class="four wide blue column">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="ui header">A SAMPLE BLOG</h1>
                    <p>Creating a blog layout using Semantic</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="eight wide column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam in purus et diam lacinia luctus gravida id nulla. Aliquam vehicula velit ac nisl ornare, eget lobortis dolor facilisis. Vestibulum in vulputate augue, a laoreet lacus. Vivamus eleifend in lectus eget egestas. In ut ligula a risus imperdiet volutpat. Vestibulum hendrerit odio diam, at placerat leo condimentum sit amet. Aenean imperdiet scelerisque mi, non tincidunt felis posuere nec. Quisque venenatis tempor urna, eget faucibus lectus ornare at. Phasellus sed turpis nibh. Vivamus rhoncus massa in ex volutpat, sit amet sagittis dolor viverra. Nulla nulla sapien, suscipit et ligula id, eleifend mollis lectus.

Nunc luctus rutrum laoreet. Ut eleifend vestibulum rhoncus. Sed sit amet ultrices tellus. Integer eleifend tortor eleifend pharetra tempor. Mauris sapien felis, maximus a tellus eu, gravida hendrerit mauris. Maecenas ullamcorper libero sit amet neque mattis, vel venenatis risus pulvinar. Proin posuere tincidunt pulvinar.

Nam vel lectus tincidunt, posuere velit vel, dictum sem. Aliquam pulvinar urna neque, id ultricies orci varius sit amet. Nam ante dui, mollis in dignissim eu, lobortis a odio. Cras nec viverra neque, id porttitor purus. Ut tristique ex ut lectus scelerisque porttitor. Fusce feugiat vulputate orci eget convallis. Nulla lacus nisl, pulvinar eu libero id, mollis egestas nunc. Curabitur dictum tempor commodo. Nam erat diam, feugiat sit amet cursus et, rutrum at lorem. Nunc condimentum dui risus, vel maximus lectus consectetur sit amet. Morbi porta pharetra molestie.

Integer id convallis neque, at consectetur ligula. Integer eu luctus mi, nec scelerisque neque. Donec in nisl rutrum dui scelerisque luctus nec venenatis mi. Proin vehicula sed nisl at porta. Sed fringilla lacus nibh, vitae iaculis eros rutrum non. Duis iaculis dolor quis sapien ornare, eu ultrices nunc ultricies. Quisque dignissim hendrerit ultricies. Suspendisse eget tellus ac urna mollis viverra. Sed ac tellus scelerisque, congue lorem a, mollis velit. Praesent hendrerit ligula mi, eget gravida enim pharetra eu. Vestibulum varius erat ut commodo congue.

In scelerisque consectetur orci, eu dignissim tortor scelerisque sed. Sed lacinia urna at tincidunt efficitur. Ut porttitor mauris a neque volutpat sagittis. Proin sagittis gravida metus quis dignissim. Proin eleifend ultrices est, id vulputate ipsum vulputate in. Suspendisse libero orci, pretium ac erat in, pretium fringilla arcu. Etiam lobortis sit amet tellus eget tempus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed porttitor ante at purus vulputate dictum.</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But, the column height doesn't take 100% of height.

I want to make it fixed like the purecss layout.
Please help me.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the columns stretch to 100% of the height of the page, you will need to set all its parents height to 100%. So you will need to go upto the root element `html` height set to 100%.

**I suggest you to use custom classes to target them.**

```css
html,
body,
.grid,
.column {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.0.7/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Blog Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/semantic.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ui padded grid">
    <div class="four wide blue column">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="ui header">A SAMPLE BLOG</h1>
        <p>Creating a blog layout using Semantic</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="eight wide column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam in purus et diam lacinia luctus gravida id nulla. Aliquam vehicula velit ac nisl ornare, eget lobortis dolor facilisis. Vestibulum in vulputate augue, a laoreet lacus. Vivamus eleifend
      in lectus eget egestas. In ut ligula a risus imperdiet volutpat. Vestibulum hendrerit odio diam, at placerat leo condimentum sit amet. Aenean imperdiet scelerisque mi, non tincidunt felis posuere nec. Quisque venenatis tempor urna, eget faucibus
      lectus ornare at. Phasellus sed turpis nibh. Vivamus rhoncus massa in ex volutpat, sit amet sagittis dolor viverra. Nulla nulla sapien, suscipit et ligula id, eleifend mollis lectus. Nunc luctus rutrum laoreet. Ut eleifend vestibulum rhoncus. Sed
      sit amet ultrices tellus. Integer eleifend tortor eleifend pharetra tempor. Mauris sapien felis, maximus a tellus eu, gravida hendrerit mauris. Maecenas ullamcorper libero sit amet neque mattis, vel venenatis risus pulvinar. Proin posuere tincidunt
      pulvinar. Nam vel lectus tincidunt, posuere velit vel, dictum sem. Aliquam pulvinar urna neque, id ultricies orci varius sit amet. Nam ante dui, mollis in dignissim eu, lobortis a odio. Cras nec viverra neque, id porttitor purus. Ut tristique ex
      ut lectus scelerisque porttitor. Fusce feugiat vulputate orci eget convallis. Nulla lacus nisl, pulvinar eu libero id, mollis egestas nunc. Curabitur dictum tempor commodo. Nam erat diam, feugiat sit amet cursus et, rutrum at lorem. Nunc condimentum
      dui risus, vel maximus lectus consectetur sit amet. Morbi porta pharetra molestie. Integer id convallis neque, at consectetur ligula. Integer eu luctus mi, nec scelerisque neque. Donec in nisl rutrum dui scelerisque luctus nec venenatis mi. Proin
      vehicula sed nisl at porta. Sed fringilla lacus nibh, vitae iaculis eros rutrum non. Duis iaculis dolor quis sapien ornare, eu ultrices nunc ultricies. Quisque dignissim hendrerit ultricies. Suspendisse eget tellus ac urna mollis viverra. Sed ac
      tellus scelerisque, congue lorem a, mollis velit. Praesent hendrerit ligula mi, eget gravida enim pharetra eu. Vestibulum varius erat ut commodo congue. In scelerisque consectetur orci, eu dignissim tortor scelerisque sed. Sed lacinia urna at tincidunt
      efficitur. Ut porttitor mauris a neque volutpat sagittis. Proin sagittis gravida metus quis dignissim. Proin eleifend ultrices est, id vulputate ipsum vulputate in. Suspendisse libero orci, pretium ac erat in, pretium fringilla arcu. Etiam lobortis
      sit amet tellus eget tempus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed porttitor ante at purus vulputate dictum.</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```